# How to change direction smoothly using SDL2 and how to keep moving when I press shift after holding a key?

Tags: c, keypress, sdl-2

It's my Code, it's a very simple tank games, I have 2 problems:

1. use WSAD to move with speed 4, when I pressing and holding shift, the speed change to 8, when I release shift, speed back to 4. But, with my code, when I press shift after holding WSAD, the tank stop, I must repress the key to move it.
2. When I press WSAD, the tank just change the direction, but not move,so when I holding d, the tank first change it's direction to right for about 0.5 second, then start to move. How to get it move smoothly?

   ```
   #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
   #include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 960;   //窗体宽度
   const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 640;  //窗体高度

   //使用旋转角度定义方向
   const int UP = 0;
   const int DOWN = 180;
   const int LEFT = 270;
   const int RIGHT = 90;
   //-------------------

   typedef struct {
       int x;
       int y;
       int width;
       int height;
       int direction;
       SDL_Texture *texture;
   } Player;

   void RenderPlayer(Player player, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
       SDL_Rect srcRect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = player.width, .h = player.height};
       SDL_Rect destRect = {.x = player.x, .y = player.y, .w = player.width / 2, .h = player.height / 2};
       SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, player.texture, &srcRect, &destRect, player.direction, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
   }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       SDL_Window *window;
       SDL_Renderer *renderer;
       if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
           printf("SDL对象初始化失败！\n");
           return -1;
       }

       if (!(window = SDL_CreateWindow("坦克大战", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL))) {
           printf("窗体创建失败！\n");
           return -1;
       }

       if (!(renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE))) {
           printf("渲染器创建失败！\n");
           return -1;
       }

       SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 76, 110, 150, 255);
       SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
       SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

       SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load("Tank01.png");
       if (!surface) {
           printf("像素集创建失败：%s\n", IMG_GetError());
           return -1;
       }

       printf("宽度：%d\n高度：%d\n", surface->w, surface->h);

       Player player1 = {(WINDOW_WIDTH - surface->w) / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT - surface->h, surface->w, surface->h, UP, SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface)};

       int speed;
       const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
       SDL_Event sdlEvent;
       while (1) {
           int flag1 = 0;
           while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent)) {
               speed = 4;
               switch (sdlEvent.type) {
                   case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                       if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_LSHIFT] && (state[SDL_SCANCODE_W] || state[SDL_SCANCODE_S] || state[SDL_SCANCODE_A] || state[SDL_SCANCODE_D])) {
                           speed = 8;
                       }
                       switch (sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym) {
                           case SDLK_w:
                               if (player1.y > 0) {
                                   player1.y -= speed;
                               }
                               player1.direction = UP;
                               break;
                           case SDLK_s:
                               if (player1.y < WINDOW_HEIGHT - player1.height / 2) {
                                   player1.y += speed;
                               }
                               player1.direction = DOWN;
                               break;
                           case SDLK_a:
                               if (player1.x > 0) {
                                   player1.x -= speed;
                               }
                               player1.direction = LEFT;
                               break;
                           case SDLK_d:
                               if (player1.x < WINDOW_WIDTH - player1.width / 2) {
                                   player1.x += speed;
                               }
                               player1.direction = RIGHT;
                               break;
                           case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                               SDL_Quit();
                               flag1 = 1;
                               break;
                       }
                       break;
                   case SDL_QUIT:
                       SDL_Quit();
                       flag1 = 1;
                       break;
               }
           }
           SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
           RenderPlayer(player1, renderer);
           SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);  //使用渲染器更新窗体

           if (flag1) {
               break;
           }
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. I couldn't reproduce your first problem with the code you provided, if I hold any of wasd and press shift the tank keeps moving.
2. The problem here is a bit hard to understand, but you're basically moving the tank only on SDL_Pressed events, meaning that the only reason your tank is moving at all is because SDL repeats the same events over and over, and because it doesn't do this very fast (polling events is kinda slow), your movement is choppy/laggy/steppy whatever you want to call it.

A fix for this is to remove the actual movement step outside your SDL_Event loop, also you should **filter out** repeat events since you've already checked them.

Meaning your code should look should be something like this

```
while (1) {
    while (SDL_Event(e)) { 
        if (event is repeated) 
             skip event
        if (UP Key is pressed)
            up_state = 1;
        if (UP key is released)
            up_state = 0;
        // etc..
    }

    // Outside the event loop
    if (up_state == 1) // if its 0 we don't add anything
        player.x -= speed;
    // and so on..
}
```

For this to work properly you'll also need to read about how to implement a **delta time** in your loop, because this will run as fast as your processor can meaning that your speed wont be regular, it might add more or less speed depending on how fast is running, which is bad.

Here is your code with these problems fixed, except the **delta time**, since I actually don't which platform you're on and I was too lazy to do it in C, I capped the framerate at 60fps with a sleep at the end, which is a very bad idea.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

// I don't know if you're on windows or linux
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 960;  //窗体宽度
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 640; //窗体高度

//使用旋转角度定义方向
const int UP = 0;
const int DOWN = 180;
const int LEFT = 270;
const int RIGHT = 90;
//-------------------

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    int direction;
    SDL_Texture *texture;
} Player;

int m_up = 0;
int m_down = 0;
int m_left = 0;
int m_right = 0;

void RenderPlayer(Player player, SDL_Renderer *renderer) {
    SDL_Rect srcRect = {.x = 0, .y = 0, .w = player.width, .h = player.height};
    SDL_Rect destRect = {.x = player.x,
                         .y = player.y,
                         .w = player.width / 2,
                         .h = player.height / 2};
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, player.texture, &srcRect, &destRect,
                     player.direction, NULL, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(window = SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH,
                                    WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL))) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
                                        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
                                            SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE))) {
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 76, 110, 150, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load("tank.png");
    if (!surface) {
        return -1;
    }

    Player player1 = {(WINDOW_WIDTH - surface->w) / 2,
                      WINDOW_HEIGHT - surface->h,
                      surface->w,
                      surface->h,
                      UP,
                      SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface)};

    int speed = 4;
    SDL_Event sdlEvent;
    int run = 1;
    while (run) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent)) {
            // Now we skip over repeat events
            if ((sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN || sdlEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP) &&
                sdlEvent.key.repeat == 0) {

                SDL_Keycode key = sdlEvent.key.keysym.sym;
                int is_pressed = sdlEvent.key.state == SDL_PRESSED;

                if (key == SDLK_LSHIFT && is_pressed) {
                    speed = 8;
                } else if (key == SDLK_LSHIFT && !is_pressed) {
                    speed = 4;
                }

                if (key == SDLK_w && is_pressed) {
                    m_up = 1;
                } else if (key == SDLK_w) {
                    m_up = 0;
                }

                if (key == SDLK_s && is_pressed) {
                    m_down = 1;
                } else if (key == SDLK_s) {
                    m_down = 0;
                }

                if (key == SDLK_a && is_pressed) {
                    m_left = 1;
                } else if (key == SDLK_a) {
                    m_left = 0;
                }

                if (key == SDLK_d && is_pressed) {
                    m_right = 1;
                } else if (key == SDLK_d) {
                    m_right = 0;
                }

                if (key == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                    run = 0;
                }

                if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                    run = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Handle the movement outside the event loop
        if (m_up && player1.y > 0)
            player1.y -= speed;
        if (m_down && player1.y < WINDOW_HEIGHT - player1.height / 2)
            player1.y += speed;
        if (m_left && player1.x > 0)
            player1.x -= speed;
        if (m_right && player1.x < WINDOW_WIDTH - player1.width / 2)
            player1.x += speed;

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        RenderPlayer(player1, renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

#ifdef _WIN32
        sleep(0.016); // asume 60 fps, horrible idea
#else
        usleep(16000);
#endif
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

the test image I was using as 'tank.png' https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BEMo.png